# HubPage and CommandBar control in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to try build my first WP8.1 app and I have a problem with CommandBar in Hub. I want to add different bar to all HubSections but I don't know how to do this :/ I tried to use SectionsInView ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661979/add-different-commandbars-to-hub-element)) but the change of CommandBar items is sooooo slow.

The second question is how can I make transparent CommandBar in HubSection? HubSection contains ListView. Now, when I try to do this, ListView bottom margin is changing and I don't see ListView under CommandBar (I don't know why...). [Look at picture](http://oi61.tinypic.com/mhx0g7.jpg).

The third question is how can I change AppBarButton color when I'm pressing it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. You can try to create a new **AppBar** programmatically in the **xaml.cs**.

Answer 2. You can change the transparency for your **AppBar**. You'll also have to do this programmatically. Choose the control that you want the **AppBars** transparency to change with, select which event you wan't the **AppBars** transparency to change with. (Make sure you have given you **AppBar** a name).

Then type this in the following line:

```
BottomBar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 24, 68, 120));
```

Make sure you change the value for the option **A**, from 0-100. This option will decide what transperency you will have. The other options like **R**, **G** % **B** will decide what color the **AppBar** will have.

Answer 3. It's not really possible, the buttons highlight relies on your devices **Accent Color**. Therefore it takes a lot of programming to change that one little action.